# cPanel: Regenerate "maildirsize" after deleting emails

Tags: email, cron, cpanel

I have a server with several email accounts and limited space.

I set up a cron job to delete emails that are older than 5 days, using this:

```
find /home/domain/mail/ -type f -name "*vps.domain*" -mtime +5 -delete
```

It works really well, but cPanel keeps informing wrong account sizes. This is because there's a file in each folder called `maildirsize` which keeps track of the dir size.

If I delete the file, cPanel says that the size is 0 bytes which is also wrong. The account seems to work OK though and the file is regenerated then.

Is there a way to regenerate these files after running that cron job? Deleting them all and wait for them to be re-generated when the account is used should in theory work, but all accounts will report being 0 bytes and I don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently there's already a script installed to do that. This is it with some paremeters:

```
/scripts/generate_maildirsize --verbose --allaccounts --force --confirm
```

Running that re-generates all maildirsize files. Works great. Appended that to the cron job and everything works fine.

Comment: I get an e-mail saying this: "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /scripts/generate_maildirsize: No such file or directory"